# How do I create alert with multiple id numbers when deleting multiple records at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a records table where every row has a delete link. When clicking delete link, a popup confirmation with a message and id of record is displayed. I also have a checkbox in every row, and multiple checkboxes can be checked and a button can be clicked to delete those multiple records at the same time.

What I want to do is make another popup confirmation message (for the delete multiple jobs button), but with all the record id's that are about to be deleted. Is that possible?

Each row's delete link looks like this:

```
<a href="delete-job.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" onclick="javascript: return confirm(\'Are you SURE you want to delete job ' . $row['id'] . '?\');">Delete</a>
```

The form wrapping the table looks like this:

```
<form name="viewjobsanddelete" method="post" action="delete-jobs.php"></form>
```

The checkbox for each row looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '" />
```

The delete button looks like this:

```
<input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" class="btn" value="Delete Multiple Jobs">
```

delete-job.php (for deleting single records/rows) has this:

```
 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // delete the entry
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error()); 

 // redirect back to the view page
 header("Location: view-jobs.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
 header("Location: view-jobs.php");
 }
```

delete-jobs.php (for deleting multiple records/rows) has this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++) {
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id='$del_id'";
    //print $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
}
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=view-jobs.php\">";
```

So where do I modify or what do I add for creating confirmation dialog window with multiple id numbers of the records/rows to be deleted?

Comment: this is HIGHLY dangerous code. you're depending on the client honoring your javascript confirmation. consider a web crawler getting into your site and simplying IGNORING all that js, and deleting EVERYTHING simply by crawling.

Comment: this is just a visual confirmation so people can make sure they clicked the right row(s).  the whole app is php and login protected, and there are usergroups in place so only a limited amount of records are displayed depending on what company or employee created the jobs in the first place.  only admins have the delete capability (not regular registered users), and non registered people can't even see that page.  don't thinks bots can get into login protected pages.

Comment: in other words, javascript can't override php protection in place.

Comment: never underestimate browsers. e.g. a pre-load function to make things "appear faster" by preloading all links on the page. legit user, properly logged in, and still nuking everything in sight because their browser thought it knew better.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i handled it.

i added class="chk" to each checkbox, then i used the following jquery...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { //if the page has been fully loaded
/* Get the checkbox values based on the class attached to each check box */

$("#viewjobsanddelete").submit(function(e){ //on submission of form

/* declare a checkbox array */
var chkArray = [];

/* look for all checkboxes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
$(".chk:checked").each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
});

/* we join the array separated by a comma */
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join(',') + ",";

/* check if there are selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
if(selected.length > 1){

    if (!confirm("You are about to delete these jobs: " + selected)) { //if click cancel instead of ok
        e.preventDefault(); //stop form submission
        return;
    }

}else{
    alert("Check one or more checkboxes first.");
    e.preventDefault(); //stop form submission
    return;
}

});

});
</script>
```